# How to know if I am using Rails 2.3 in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a client that is running a Linux VPS with a Ruby on Rails site. There is a way to prove that the site is not running rails 2.3.14 without enter to the VPS? Something like to see if have turbolinks for example. Because turbolinks not exist in rails 2.3.14.

Comment: If you do not have the ability to view the code or open a shell on the server, please clarify that in your question—that you would like to tell which major version of rails the application is using from a request or webpage and cannot access the code or server.

Comment: Ok I change the question. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: I just want to know if is not rails 2.3. That is enough.

Comment: No easy way, because of reverse-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the rails entry in the `Gemfile.lock`. It will look like this

```
rails (5.1.1)
  actioncable (= 5.1.1)
  ...
```

The number in parentheses will indicate the version the application is using.

Comment: I need something without enter to the VPS.

Comment: Something that you can see just looking some behavior of the web page.

Comment: There is a big difference between rail 2.3 and rails 5. There must be something

Answer (score 0):

The way you determine the version of a Rails application is by examining the sourcecode. There is no other way that you can depend on.

Also, if the VPS contains the only copy of the source you have larger problems to consider than what version of Rails it is.